# javascript make a numbers to be multiples of 150

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to get numbers to be multiples of 150.

```
(all the num > 0)

if num = 0.333333 => output 150
if num = 149.9 => output 150
if num = 150 => output 150
if num = 150.1 => output 300
if num = 302 => output 450
...
```

Here is my code so far, using `ceil()`:

```
var num = '12';
document.write(Math.ceil((num/150)*150) + "<br />")
// Output 12, not 150;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Get rid of one set of brackets: `Math.ceil(num/150) * 150`.

Comment: right, break this brackets could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple algebra, sir:

```
(num / 150) * 150 = num
```

Substituting `'12'` (yes, a string):

```
(num / 150) * 150 = 12
```

If you want *all* numbers to map to multiples of `150`, then just divide them by 150 and *then* `floor` the result to get an integer:

```
150 * math.floor(num / 150)
```

Or `ceil` it:

```
150 * math.ceil(num / 150)
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. Simply multiply after the rounding operation:

```
function ceil150(x) {
    return Math.ceil(x / 150) * 150;
}

alert(ceil150(0.333333));
alert(ceil150(149.9));
alert(ceil150(150));
alert(ceil150(150.1));
alert(ceil150(302));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WEdSu/

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be

```
var num = 12;
var result = 150 * Math.ceil((num * 1.0)/150);
```

The multiplication by 1.0 ensures that input is converted to a floating point value - otherwise you may end up with integer division and get 12 / 150 = 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = '12';
document.write(Math.ceil(num/150)*150) + "<br />")
```

Your parentheses were off by just a little.